# VFS forgot to sign my checklist and gave me back unsigned without any reciept

Tags: student-visas

The vfs guy forgot to sign my checklist after i signed it and gave back to me unsigned, then he didn't gave me any reciept to collect my passport later on. Is there a problem? Its been 15 days i never got any email even the one that i have submitted everything and the process is began.

Comment: Ask. it seems a very new staff member, so .. better to let them know, so that ev. problem are quickly corrected.

Comment: Any update on what happened with this?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Voting to put on hold.